# /i18n/setlang/ HTTP/1.1 302 set_language dosen't work

Tags: python, django, localization

Configured localization, but language switching does not occur, in the console is issued "POST /i18n/setlang/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

Settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    project_dir + "/apps/locale",
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['src/templates/', ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
...
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
...
```

in template:

```
    <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
        <select name="language">
            {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
            {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
            {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
            {% for language in languages %}
                <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                    {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                </option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
```

Generated localizations, translated and compiled

Comment: in settings do you have `USE_I18N = True`

Comment: yes, in settings 
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True